# FactoryGirl pattern for required booleans

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I have a class that I want to initialize with FactoryGirl, which is a type of attempt. It has a success attribute boolean, which always needs to be set, to either true or false.

What's the idiomatic way of initalizing it with FactoryGirl? Have the base factory be success and then making a descendant factory for failure?

Comment: there is no idiomatic way. It depends on your design only. It can default to either `true` or `false`.

Comment: You can also use a trait instead of separate factories. Set the default attribute in the factory definition , and in the trait overwrite it with the opposite value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most idiomatic way I could think of, would be to define “abstract” factory with two traits:

```
factory :entity do
  set_everything_save_for_attempt

  trait :entity_succeeded { attempt true }
  trait :entity_failed    { attempt false }
end
```

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought of as well, but the documentation I looked at had no mention of "abstract" factories

Comment: Well, literally this term (“abstract factories”) is not mentioned, but technically any factory that can’t be instantiated directly is _abstract_. `:create` on it will fail due to absence of mandatory parameter.

Comment: Yeah I understood your meaning, but I didn't see this pattern mentioned. My previous comment was supposed to be a not e of thanks. :)